# PHP - Store image to database or file better?

Tags: php

PHP - Store image to database or file better?

The image requires to change to base64 and send to the client everytime.
So, is it good to convert the image to base64 storing to database, so as to reduce the throughput to convert it everytime when loading the image

Comment: Overhead of conversion to base64 on insert and convert back whenever you need to display it; at least twice the volume of space as base 64 converted than it would take up as a straight binary (on filesystem)..... doesn't sound very good to me, like a lose/lose situation

Comment: It is because I need to convert the image to base64, then encrypt the base64 and send it as json to android device. Why I need to change it to base64, because I cannot find a way to encrypt the image file and send to android. Yet, base64 does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid this, your db will fill up quick if you have lots of images. I would store to file.